# Table View not filling with data

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

So I am trying to implement a simple `UITableView` and when I compile and run my code it presents an empty table. Here is my code:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
       var tableView = UITableView()
       var items:[String] = ["foo", "ban", "bar"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       tableView.frame = self.view.bounds
       self.view!.addSubview(tableView)
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return self.items.count
    } 

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) ->    UITableViewCell! {
       var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as  UITableViewCell
       var theItem:String = items[indexPath.row]
       cell.textLabel.text = theItem
       return cell
    }
}
```

Why are the items not being displayed in the table?

Comment: I'm not a swift guy but seems like you are using storyboard for your table view but in your code it points to a brand new table view.

Comment: why would you say the poster is using a storyboard ? He is adding the tableview programatically...

Comment: Then he will need to initialise the cell as well because it will return nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are not setting the tableViews delegate and datasource, try doing that and make sure your tableview delegate/datasource methods are being called...

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```